React Native Turbo module custom Type code gen
I created react. native turbo module with backward compatibility template,
I use code gen to generate primite types that I can use it in ios Objective c
Now I created a simple interface
interface Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  employee: Employee;
}

export interface Spec extends TurboModule {
  sendPersonRecieveModifedDepartment(person: Person): Promise<Person>;
}

I am able to access the person values in objective c class, but I want to return the person with updated values but getting error as Use of undeclared identifier 'person'


(void)sendPersonRecieveModifedDepartment:(JS::NativeBlockidPlugin::Person
&)person resolve:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
reject:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject {
NSLog(@"%@", person.firstName());
person.firstName = "updated name";
resolve(person); //Use of undeclared identifier 'person'    }


Use of undeclared identifier 'person'

